# Killoren Lifespan?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races

How long do the Killoren live? All the *Races of the Wild* splatbook says is that they "live very long lives." I have come across a few conflicting answers online, but it all seems to be user created content (on forums, no source, etc). If there is an actual answer please provide a source.

Answer (score 6):

*Race of Wild p 106*

> **Aging Effects**
>
> Killoren age normally through the old age category, but they never reach the venerable age category and can live indefinitely should they choose to do so.

Killoren never die of old age. They reach middle age after 30 years, and are considered old after 100, but they never age beyond that. They do still get the physical stat reduction and the metal stat increases though. They can die like any other creature, but age and time will not be the cause. This is the only RAW data that I could find on this matter.